# python program not running is html webpage

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

this my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>pyscript demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<py-script src="pythonfile.py"></py-script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this my python program code

```
lst = [["a", 45], ["b", 40], ["c", 18], ["d", 17]]

name = input("Enter your name:")

print("Searching in list")
for item in lst:
    if item[0] == name:
        print("name:", item[0], "age:", item[1])
```

I have tried to run python program in html webpage the html web page is working and the python code is not running is html webpage

Comment: try to put your code inline, if getting file not found error. Also, try to open this HTML file in chrome browser. somehow Safri did not work for me and worked well in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have vs-code, install "Live-Server" extension and open live-server.

or

open terminal/command-prompt in the same folder. Assuming you have named your html file as "index.html", enter following command in terminal:

`python3 -m http.server 8000`

then open `http://0.0.0.0:8000` in your browser

Answer (score 0):

You are facing issue as mentioned below.

```
Access to fetch at 'pythonfile.py' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
```

then you can try this instead of attaching a python file write it inline.

```
<py-script>
    lst = [["a", 45], ["b", 40], ["c", 18], ["d", 17]]

    name = input("Enter your name:")

    print("Searching in list")
    for item in lst:
        if item[0] == name:
            print("name:", item[0], "age:", item[1])
</py-script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When some thing does not work, please describe what is happening instead. In a web browser you can get more information from the developer tools Console, which can be opened by the menu or probably by pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)).

As `GauravGiri` already answered, the most probable reason is the difference between opening an HTML file locally and visiting it through a webserver:
HTML Sites are not allowed to read the contents of other local files on your computer, while accessing them from the same webserver is allowed.